# Clojure: unable to run Sparkling

Tags: apache-spark, clojure

I'm trying to use the [Sparkling library](https://github.com/gorillalabs/sparkling) to use Spark from Clojure. Yet, even a simple code like this:

```
(ns sql-spark.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [yesql.core :refer [defquery]]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [clojure.edn :as edn]
            [sparkling.conf :as conf]
            [sparkling.core :as spark]))

(defn -main []
  (println "Hi"))
```

Ends up with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf, compiling:(sparkling/conf.clj:1:1)
```

I have Spark installed, and I've used it many times with Scala. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**
`project.clj`:

```
(defproject sql-spark "1.0.0"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [yesql "0.5.3"]
                 [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.32"]
                 [gorillalabs/sparkling "1.2.5"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot sql-spark.core)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I was missing `[org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 "1.6.1"]` in my `:dependencies` section